# trying to execute a script as i open a tkinter window. i want the outputs of the script to be printed in continuous on the tkinter window

Tags: python, button, tkinter, printing, continuous

i´m trying to execute a script as i open a tkinter window. i want the outputs of the script to be printed in continuous on the tkinter window, without i´ve to press any command button. i´ve already read some questions in the site, took some ideas but with no success for what i want. Thanks for any help.

```
# code for tkinter window
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

loop_active = True
while loop_active:
    root.update()
    root["bg"] = "black"
    root.title('windowtitle')
    root.update_idletasks()
    width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    heigth = root.winfo_screenheight()

root(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: don't you get any error message ? `root(root)` is not correct. It is not good idea to run loop in any `GUI`. Better use `root.after` to run some code periodically.

Comment: you print nothing - so want do you expect ?

Comment: if you want to run other script in this code then better run it in thread - to not block `mainloop()`

Comment: Read [How do you run your own code alongside Tkinter's event loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459083/how-do-you-run-your-own-code-alongside-tkinters-event-loop)

Comment: The root(root) seems to work fine.

Comment: I didnt put anything to print because i dont know how.